# Typescript interface with never typed fields

Tags: typescript, typescript3.8

Given the following interface, what would be a valid assignable value?

```
interface A {
  x: number,
  y: never
}
```

What I expected was that `const a: A = { x: 1 }` would work, but it errors saying field `y` is required. As soon as I put `y` in there, it says that the value is not assignable to `never`.

My actual use case is something like this:

```
interface Context<T extends MyRequest> {
  id: string;
  token: T extends AuthenticateRequest ? string : never;
}

interface AuthenticatedRequest extends MyRequest { ... }
```

Here I am unable to create a value for `Context<MyRequest>` since it says `token` is missing.

A workaround I currently have is:

```
type Context<T extends MyRequest> = {
  id: string;
} & (T extends AuthenticatedRequest ? {
  token: string;
} : {})
```

but for obvious reasons, this looks ugly...

Any ideas how I do this correctly ?

Comment: I think you might want to use `undefined` in place of `never`.

Comment: An interface with a never member is as good as never itself, in that no value of that interface can ever exist. You can use `undefined` instead, but it will not make the property optional. I think your current workaround is good, why are you unhappy with it? Any concrete reason, or just I would rather it be an interface ?

Comment: The idea was to not have to set that field while defining a value for the type, while also making the interface look pretty simple (I will be adding many more conditional fields so it will begin to look messy). Though as I understand, the method mention as workaround is the right way to go here and I don't have an alternative...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on points mentioned by @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir and @Maciej Sikora, the workaround is the right way to go for the type definition I need. An `interface` cannot have a field of type `never`, since it can't be assigned a valid value, thereby making the interface useless.

Here's what I finally used for my code:

```
type Context<T extends MyRequest> = Readonly<
  {
    logger: MyLogger;
    timestamp?: number;
  } & (T extends AuthenticatedRequest
    ? {
        token: Token;
        user: string;
      }
    : {}) &
    (T extends GameRequest
      ? {
          gameId: string;
        }
      : {}) &
    (T extends ETagRequest
      ? {
          etag: string;
        }
      : {}) &
    (T extends UnParameterizedRequest
      ? {}
      : {
          params: Record<string, string | undefined>;
        })
>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Type `never` is representation of empty type. What does it mean - there is no value which belongs to this type, what means you have always compilation error if you use it.

What you need is conditional type at higher level, consider:

```
type Context<T extends MyRequest> = T extends AuthenticateRequest ? {
  id: string;
  token: string;
} : { id: string };
```

Such approach remove a burden of setting `undefined` for `token`. If `token` is required, so for `T extends AuthenticateRequest` it is a string, if it is not, the `token` field is not there.

Comment: Yup that seems to make sense. I will be adding more fields with different `T extends AnotherInterface` conditionals so it will get messy, but it looks like the "workaround" is actually the right the way to go

Comment: I don't think setting explicitly undefined is correct approach, this state should not be considered in the case of `T extends AuthenticateRequest`. If we go into - make impossible states impossible, then what I have written is correct approach.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean as I'm not using undefined. I've put my final version as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your type to string or undefined. The `never` type is used when a variable will never be assigned a value, More on that [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never).

This approach ought to solve your problem I think.

```js
interface A {
  x: number,
  y: string | undefined
}
```